How can I perform a SIESTA calculation using VdW functional?
To solve siesta: gold atomic layer splitting during geometry optimization of MoS2 and gold heterostructure, I tried GGA-PBE pseudopotential files generated by different groups. In all cases, regardless of whether the DFTD3 correction was added, the gold crystal structure collapsed during geometry optimization.
I am going to use van der Waals corrected functionals provided by SIESTA. I set the fdf flags XC.Functional VDW and XC.Authors KBM, but failed. what else should I do? Do I need external pseudopotential files? Do I have to compile SIESTA with libGridXC library? What is the connection between the above fdf flags and external pseudopotential files?
When I didn't include the pseudopotential files in the current directory, the program stopped immediately and warned me that the pseudopotential files were not found.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Did you generate/obtain the pseudopotentials files for vdW/KBM?

No, Sir, I didn't know how to do that. Do I need pseudopotential file generation tool like ATOM？

@xinbiaowang generally you don't need to prefix questions with siesta, the tag handles the association

Thank you for your reminder, Sir.@nickpapior

Yes, you need the corresponding pseudopotentials.

@Camps Thank you, Sir! I will generate my own vdws pseudopotentials and give feedback later!
